# Quais as diferença entre AlarmClock e AlarmManager?

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

Quais as diferenças entre o AlarmClock e o AlarmManager?

Comment: só pra saber, em qual das categorias se enquadra na parte de repostas ruins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As classes têm propósitos diferentes:

[AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) disponibiliza um conjunto de constantes cuja função é facilitar a criação de um *Intent* para lançar/controlar uma aplicação, existente no dispositivo, que responda aos *Intent* `ACTION_SET_ALARM` e `ACTION_SET_TIMER`.

O seguinte código chama a aplicação padrão, ou pede para escolher uma, e regista um alarme para as 15:30.

```
Intent createAlarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
createAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 15);
createAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30);
startActivity(createAlarm);
```

[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) é uma classe que 
permite registar um *Intent* para lançar a sua aplicação(*Activity*), serviço ou *BroadcastReceiver*, a determinado dia e hora.

O código seguinte define um alarme para lançar um *BroadcastReceiver* todos os dias às 10 horas:

```
//Definir a hora de início
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(context, ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver.class);
PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1234, tarefaIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//Definir o alarme para acontecer todos os dias às 10 horas
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                 AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, tarefaPendingIntent);
```

Alguns exemplos que usam AlarmManger:

- [Como executar um método em tempo determinado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26275/2541)
- [Notificação em uma certa hora sem necessidade de abrir o programa.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64131/2541)
- [Notificações em tempo determinado e ao ligar celular.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58040/2541)

Usando o *AlarmManager* pode criar uma aplicação tipo "despertador" para que possa ser lançada/controlada por *Intents* criados com a ajuda do *AlarmClock*.

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de serem duas classe totalmente distintas, veja abaixo uma breve explicação sobre cada uma:

### [AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html)

{*public final class AlarmClock* }

Contém um conjunto de constantes e extras que podem ser usados para iniciar uma *activity* para definir um novo alarme em um aplicativo de "despertador".

Exemplo:

- `AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR`: Hora do alarme a ser ajustada
- `AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES`: Minuto do alarme a ser ajustado
- `AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS`: Dias do alarme a ser ajustado
- `AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE`: Mesagem do alarme
- `AlarmClock.EXTRA_RINGTONE`: Um toque para ser disparado no alarme
- `AlarmClock.EXTRA_VIBRATE`: Se irá vibrar
- outros

Como é usado:

```
Intent alarme = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
alarme.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 10);
startActivity(alarme);
```

### [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

{*public class AlarmManager*  }

Permite agendar sua aplicação para ser executado em algum instante futuro. Quando um alarme dispara, uma intensão é transmitida pelo sistema, então seu aplicativo responde a essa intenção de transmissão e executa uma ação, tal como abrir o aplicativo, notificar o usuário via notificação na barra de *status* ou realizar outro tipo de ação.

Em vários tipos de aplicativos, necessitamos que alguma ação seja agendada para ser executada algum tempo depois, ou que seja feita periodicamente fora do ciclo de vida de sua aplicação. Para isso o sistema Android disponibiliza a o recurso de `Alarm` através da classe `AlarmManager` que utiliza melhor os recursos do sistema do que se tivéssemos controlando através ou [`Timer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Como é usado:

```
AlarmManager alarme=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class); 
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
alarme.setRepeating(
    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), PERIOD, pi);
```

Para saber mais detalhes, consulte a documentação sobre [AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) e [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).